# Swift - UITableView from Storyboard is always nil

Tags: swift

I am having a very frustrating issue from a very simple situation. I just want to connect and populate a UITableView from the Storyboard. Below is a picture of my situation.

[image: View of StoryBoard and UIViewController class]

As you can see, I just have a normal UITableView in my Storyboard, with a normal UITableViewCell set up as a prototype. The prototype cell has a Cell Identifier and the UITableView is properly hooked up to the IBOutlet in the UIViewController class. The UIViewController is assigned to be my UIViewController subclass in the Storyboard. Yet, the UITableView is nil in viewDidLoad(), and it is nil everywhere outside of viewDidLoad(), it is always nil. I have redone this three times now. I have restarted XCode, and I have restarted my computer. Is there something I am missing?

EDIT: The solution - Don't load the view controller programmatically in the app delegate... load from the Storyboard. Facepalm.

Comment: can you please try the outlet variable with '?', like `@IBOutlet var beaconTableView: UITableView?`, and reconnecting it?

Comment: That doesn't work...just causes more errors

Comment: I know you have the data and delegate set to self in code. But have you tried control dragging from the table view to the vc?  Sometimes I find that will work better.  Drag to the yellow circle top left.

Comment: Yeah I've tried that as well... no dice

Answer (score 4):

Override the setter for tableView to check if that is really working.

```
class MyController: UIViewController {
   @IBOutlet var beaconTableView: UITableView! {
     didSet {
       print("tableView is set")
     }
   }
   .........
}
```

This will help you debug further about it. If the setter is not called at all. Remove the table from storyboard completely. Add a new one and create IBOutlet connection again. See if that works !

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The TableView is indeed not being set ever. Not even if I remove it completely and add it again..this is terrible. Any other ideas?

Comment: Well then there is something wrong in your code can you check if viewDidLoad gets triggered ?

Comment: It definitely does because if you look at that picture I am in a debug session currently halted in viewDidLoad

Comment: Ok then instead of connecting the outlet, try, dragging from the storyboard to the code and create a new tableView property. Try if that works

Comment: That also does not work. I'm about to quit coding forever

Comment: Ha ha that usually happens when you get frustrated with tools and could not get over it. Believe me, it is just small thing that you might be missing somewhere. Could you provide me the code or just storyboard and viewcontroller, if possible such that I could look at it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81328/discussion-between-angerboy-and-generatorofone).

Answer (score 0):

Instantiating the Controller from the storyboard helps.